# Reshape pandas data frame from long to wide having string/text responses

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table, pandas-melt

I have a survey dataset, a part of which I need to expand as columns having textual responses to rating questions asked. The dataset is large, what is the best way of doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
  pd.DataFrame({'S.No': {0: 63.0,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: 204.0,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 238.0,
  9: nan,
  10: nan,
  11: nan,
  12: 292.0,
  13: nan,
  14: nan,
  15: nan,
  16: 332.0,
  17: nan,
  18: nan,
  19: nan},
 'ID': {0: 251,
  1: 251,
  2: 251,
  3: 251,
  4: 252,
  5: 252,
  6: 252,
  7: 252,
  8: 253,
  9: 253,
  10: 253,
  11: 253,
  12: 254,
  13: 254,
  14: 254,
  15: 254,
  16: 255,
  17: 255,
  18: 255,
  19: 255},
 'Name': {0: 'Bob',
  1: 'Bob',
  2: 'Bob',
  3: 'Bob',
  4: 'Foo',
  5: 'Foo',
  6: 'Foo',
  7: 'Foo',
  8: 'Mike',
  9: 'Mike',
  10: 'Mike',
  11: 'Mike',
  12: 'Mary',
  13: 'Mary',
  14: 'Mary',
  15: 'Mary',
  16: 'Bar',
  17: 'Bar',
  18: 'Bar',
  19: 'Bar'},
 'User Function': {0: 'Sales',
  1: 'Sales',
  2: 'Sales',
  3: 'Sales',
  4: 'Mktg',
  5: 'Mktg',
  6: 'Mktg',
  7: 'Mktg',
  8: 'Finance',
  9: 'Finance',
  10: 'Finance',
  11: 'Finance',
  12: 'Sales',
  13: 'Sales',
  14: 'Sales',
  15: 'Sales',
  16: 'Mktg',
  17: 'Mktg',
  18: 'Mktg',
  19: 'Mktg'},
 'Business Unit': {0: 'BU1',
  1: 'BU1',
  2: 'BU1',
  3: 'BU1',
  4: 'BU2',
  5: 'BU2',
  6: 'BU2',
  7: 'BU2',
  8: 'BU3',
  9: 'BU3',
  10: 'BU3',
  11: 'BU3',
  12: 'BU1',
  13: 'BU1',
  14: 'BU1',
  15: 'BU1',
  16: 'BU2',
  17: 'BU2',
  18: 'BU2',
  19: 'BU2'},
 'Gender': {0: 'Male',
  1: 'Male',
  2: 'Male',
  3: 'Male',
  4: 'Male',
  5: 'Male',
  6: 'Male',
  7: 'Male',
  8: 'Male',
  9: 'Male',
  10: 'Male',
  11: 'Male',
  12: 'Female',
  13: 'Female',
  14: 'Female',
  15: 'Female',
  16: 'Male',
  17: 'Male',
  18: 'Male',
  19: 'Male'},
 'Primary Exit Reason': {0: 'Policy',
  1: 'Policy',
  2: 'Policy',
  3: 'Policy',
  4: 'Team',
  5: 'Team',
  6: 'Team',
  7: 'Team',
  8: 'Navigation',
  9: 'Navigation',
  10: 'Navigation',
  11: 'Navigation',
  12: 'Others',
  13: 'Others',
  14: 'Others',
  15: 'Others',
  16: 'Policy',
  17: 'Policy',
  18: 'Policy',
  19: 'Policy'},
 'Primary Question': {0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D',
  4: 'E',
  5: 'F',
  6: 'G',
  7: 'H',
  8: 'I',
  9: 'J',
  10: 'K',
  11: 'L',
  12: 'M',
  13: 'N',
  14: 'O',
  15: 'P',
  16: 'A',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'D'},
 'Primary Response': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: 'Agree',
  5: 'Agree',
  6: 'No',
  7: nan,
  8: 'Agree',
  9: 'Agree',
  10: 'No',
  11: nan,
  12: nan,
  13: nan,
  14: nan,
  15: nan,
  16: nan,
  17: nan,
  18: nan,
  19: nan},
 'Secondary Exit Reason': {0: 'Policy',
  1: 'Policy',
  2: 'Policy',
  3: 'Policy',
  4: 'Others',
  5: 'Others',
  6: 'Others',
  7: 'Others',
  8: 'Transport',
  9: 'Transport',
  10: 'Transport',
  11: 'Transport',
  12: 'Policy',
  13: 'Policy',
  14: 'Policy',
  15: 'Policy',
  16: 'Policy',
  17: 'Policy',
  18: 'Policy',
  19: 'Policy'},
 'Secondary Question': {0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D',
  4: 'M',
  5: 'N',
  6: 'O',
  7: 'P',
  8: 'Q',
  9: 'R',
  10: 'S',
  11: 'T',
  12: 'A',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'C',
  15: 'D',
  16: 'A',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'D'},
 'Secondary Response': {0: 'Agree',
  1: 'Agree',
  2: 'Yes',
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan,
  10: nan,
  11: nan,
  12: 'Agree',
  13: 'Agree',
  14: 'No',
  15: nan,
  16: 'Highly Agree',
  17: 'Agree',
  18: "I'm unaware",
  19: nan},
 'Feedback Question': {0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'B',
  6: 'C',
  7: 'D',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'C',
  11: 'D',
  12: 'A',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'C',
  15: 'D',
  16: 'A',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'D'},
 'Feedback Reason': {0: '4',
  1: '8',
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: '4',
  5: '7',
  6: 'NO ALL GOOD',
  7: 'NO\n',
  8: '4',
  9: '6',
  10: 'No',
  11: 'No',
  12: '5',
  13: '6',
  14: 'No',
  15: 'No',
  16: '5',
  17: '10',
  18: 'YES GOOD XP',
  19: 'Yes'}})
```

Above is a reproducible dataset. It is required to expand `Primary Question`, `Secondary Question` and `Feedback Question` into columns, having `Primary Response`, `Secondary Response` and `Feedback Response` as the values to those columns. Rest all variables don't change so remain in a single row such as `'S.No'`, `'ID'`, `'Name'`, `'User Function'`, `'Business Unit'`, `'Gender'`,
'Issues' . Each ID consists of 4 rows

I tried using `groupby()` ID and then `unstack()` -ing the required columns but that did not work. Also tried `melt` and `pivot`.

```
df.melt(id_vars=['S.No','ID','Name','User Function','Business Unit','Gender','Primary Exit Reason'], 
              var_name='var')
```

I'm not sure how to break the columns each into separate columns

Output expected:
[image]

Comment: I was talking a look at this, however, could I request you show an example of what you want the final output to look like?

Comment: @dimButTries have added to the question

Comment: One way of doing this could be: 1. drop S.No 2. create a subset of the dataset basis the columns which dont change and those which do. 3. Using pivot_table on 3 different data sets for Primary Question, Secondary Question, Feedback Question and then 4. Merge all together

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output as your expected, please note I only transformed from wide to long Feedback Reasons, Secondary Responses and Primary Response, as they contained information I could easily identify.

The steps are reproducible for you to add the additional columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Step 2: Group by Name
grouped_df = df.groupby('Name')

# Step 3: Transform Feedback Reason from long to wide format
feedback_reason_df = grouped_df['Feedback Reason'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack().add_prefix('Feedback Reason ')

# Combine the original grouped DataFrame with the feedback_reason_df
result_df = grouped_df.first().join(feedback_reason_df)

# Remove the duplicate column
result_df = result_df.drop(columns='Feedback Reason')

# Step 4: Transform Secondary Response from long to wide format
secondary_response_df = grouped_df['Secondary Response'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack().add_prefix('Secondary Response ')

# Add the secondary_response_df to the result_df
result_df = result_df.join(secondary_response_df)

# Step 5: Transform Primary Response from long to wide format
primary_response_df = grouped_df['Primary Response'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack().add_prefix('Primary Response ')

# Add the primary_response_df to the result_df
result_df = result_df.join(primary_response_df)

result_df = result_df.fillna('')

result_df
```

**Additional**
Here is a function to make the code more readable and reproducible.

```
# Function to transform a column from long to wide format and merge with result_df
def transform_column(column_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Transform the specified column from long to wide format and merge with result_df.
    
    Args:
        column_name: The name of the column to transform.
    
    Returns:
        The result_df DataFrame with the specified column transformed and merged.
    """
    column_df = grouped_df[column_name].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack().add_prefix(column_name + ' ')
    return result_df.join(column_df)
```

You can use the function by `result_df = transform_column('Feedback Reason')`